# Polymer paper-dropdown-menu

Tags: polymer-1.0, paper-elements

I am trying with `paper-dropdown-menu`. It seems to be working on Google Chrome but on Firefox the dropdown menu is not coming up. Is this only compatible with Chrome browser?

Comment: Are you including the web components polyfill? The web components standards are not fully supported in old browsers so polyfills are needed for most browsers

Comment: Did you try opening the demo page on firefox?

Comment: @Sirk - Yes, the demo works on Firefox.

Comment: @Ben - webcomponentjs file included in my application. 
<script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>.
I thought this is the one required for cross browser compatibility. Am I missing something else?

Comment: Could you post some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">

<dom-module id="cc-dropdown">
  <template>
    {{selectedData}}
    <paper-dropdown-menu label="Environment">
      <paper-menu class="dropdown-content" attr-for-selected="value" selected="{{selectedData}}">
        <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{data}}">
          <paper-item value="{{item}}">{{item}}</paper-item>
        </template>
      </paper-menu>
    </paper-dropdown-menu>
  </template>

  <script>
    (function() {
      'use strict';

      Polymer({
        is: 'cc-dropdown',

        properties: {
          data: {
            type: Array,
            value: ["Stage", "Prod"],
            notify: true
          },
          selectedData: {
            type: String,
            value: "Stage",
            notify: true
          }
        }
      });
    })();
  </script>

</dom-module>
```

Here is the one that works for me

Comment: Thanks! I will try this. However why is {{selectedData}} just beneath <template> opening tag? Does this have any specific significance?

Comment: I see why {{selectedData}} is there. Your solution works perfectly. Thanks!